# Difference Between Two Times Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to calculate the time it takes in minutes for an action to be completed. Using a simple datediff dax would be my go to, but run into an issue where an action takes longer than one day.

Code i'm trying

```
Time Taken = DATEDIFF(Sheet1[Start Time],Sheet1[End Time],MINUTE)
```

And here is an example of the outcome.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmTTE.jpg)

In the last cell, you can see that the action takes a day to complete so the result is providing an answer of -149 minutes which i dont want.

What can I do to get this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A calculated column of:

```
Time Taken =
DATEDIFF (
    'Table'[Start Date] + 'Table'[Start Time],
    'Table'[End Date] + 'Table'[End Time],
    MINUTE
)
```

Gives:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Time Taken = 
    DATEDIFF(Sheet1[Start Time],Sheet1[End Time],MINUTE)+
    DATEDIFF(Sheet1[Start Date],Sheet1[End Date],DAY)*60*24
  -- DATEDIFF(Sheet1[Start Date],Sheet1[End Date],MINUTE) --?
```